# Separate htaccess files or conditions for wordpress multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, multisite

Is there a way to add a Condition to the htaccess file so it only executes a command if in the right subdomain?
It would also work if there is a seperate htaccess file für only the subdomain.

I want this because my hoster gave me a command to put in a htaccess of my subdomain to change its php version. I need this to test, if the multisite works with higher php versions.

Is there a way to do this? And if so, how?

Edit:
I want to add this Line, but only apply it to a single subdomain:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php72 .php
```

My htaccess is a basic multisite htaccess

Comment: What does your htaccess look like now? and what command do you want changed in it for testing?

Comment: If you’re on Apache 2.4, you should be able to do this using https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if The very first example here basically matches your case already, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. If you post this as an answer, I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache 2.4 allows you to use *expressions* in the [`<if>` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if), so you can easily check the host name used in the request, and wrap your `AddHandler` for changing the PHP version into that.

The first example under https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples pretty much matches the use case you have here already.